# Javascript Date() initialization in bad format

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, synchronization

I'm writing javascript multiplayer game, my server code is in nodejs.
I need to synchronize time between server and client.

At server side i call Date() and send the date string to client.
Client recieves:

```
Tue Apr 28 2015 15:37:01 GMT+0000 (UTC)
```

After initialization with:

```
var time = Date("Tue Apr 28 2015 15:37:01 GMT+0000 (UTC)");
```

the time variable set to local time is:

```
Tue Apr 28 2015 17:37:03 GMT+0200 (CEST).
```

If i run my server localy then time is importing correctly.
Is problem in different time format, CEST vs UTC ?

Thank you for answers

Comment: `time` has no format. Only when you show (stringify) it, it will use the local timezone for formatting the string. If you explicitly use `time.toUTCString()`, it won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send from server date in milliseconds format and then converting milliseconds to the date in required format.

Server:

var time = new Date().getTime();

Cleint:

var date = new Date(time);

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to handle the timezones in JS.

**Set UTC time across system**

use `.setUTCHours()`
[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCHours) you can see how to use it.

**Create a new UTC Date**

`new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second))`

Date.UTC is explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)

**Correct the difference in timezones manually**

```
var d = new Date(xiYear, xiMonth, xiDate);
d.setTime( d.getTime() + d.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000 );
```